# uiscrollview in viewcontroller in modal segue

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitableview, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I'm using Xcode 4.6 to build an iOS 6.x tabbar application and using Storyboard's.  Inside each tabbed view, there is no problem adding a UIScrollView and interacting with any of the elements that are placed therein.

However... when I tap a button to transition to a new view in my storyboard using a Modal Segue, the scroll view doesn't work in the modal view.

**Example:**

Both TestViewController.h and TRViewController.h contain code similar to this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
```

In the viewDidLoad method on in both TestViewController.m and TRViewController.m:

```
[_scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
```

Then in IB, the outlet is hooked up properly to the view:

[image]

So my code is replicated / the same across IB, .h, and .m for each of the views.  Works in one area, but not the other.  Beyond that, the only other block of what I think might be relevant to my problem might be from the segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"trSegue"]) {        
    TRViewController *_trVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    _trVC.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Am I just missing something so totally obvious?  I'm thinking it's going to be a palm to forward moment once I see the solution...

Thoughts / comments?

Thanks in advance!
- Drew

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  You have to put your UIScrollView in another another empty UIView. Your hierarchy will look something like this in your interface builder:

[image]

The reason being is because of the way a modal segue displays your content.  When you do a push segue it actually pushes the ViewController onto the top most layer of the navigation stack, whereas with a modal segue it changes what is displayed on screen.  I'm not sure if this will cause apple to reject your app or not but it works.

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar problem with a push segue, and solved it by doing this. When returning to the VC containing the scrollview-in-a-UIView though, it was messed up - I solved this by setting the content offset manually to 0,0 in viewWillAppear().

Answer (score 0):

Well... I found that if I just change the segue from a Modal to a Push... it works great without any additional tweaks / adjustments. I think I'll just go this route instead of screwing around with it any further.

That said, I'd still love to find out a way to do this (if possible).